# NuGet package messed up project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I installed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/5.1.2) NuGet package through the Package Manager Console. It messed up my project and since `System.Net.Http` is missing so it is impossible to build my ASP MVC WebApi project anymore.

I tried removing references to `System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll` from the project and adding the previous one (that used to work) and regardless of which I used now, the `Http` part of the namespace can't be found.

Have you ever had this problem ? I read trashing the project and starting from scratch solved it for others, but that's not really a solution in my book.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the nuget package?

Comment: This, and many other scenarios, is one of the big advantages to using version control (like Git, SVN, etc). Just undo all the changes. It also lets you see exactly what changes a NuGet install actually made and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trashed the project and restarted a new one (Web API). I'm just drag and dropping class files back in the new one.

It wasn't under source control. That'll teach me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this in Package Manager Console:

`Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Reinstall`

If you get any errors, comment below.

Comment: It never actually installed, it went into a rollback phase after failing to install rolling back more than was useful to roll back apparently. I think I'll just trash Web API and go back to ASMX.